# How to initiate a next step in the waterfall dialog when task module submit is triggered?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I call Task module in the middle of the waterfall dialog, 2nd step in the waterfall dialog. When submit is called from the task module(web page), I get the task/submit activity in OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync which is in the Bot class. Now, how to respond to the waterfall dialog, so that next step in the waterfall dialog will be executed.

```
    protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync(
       ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, 
       TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, 
       CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
       var reply = MessageFactory.Text("OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync Value: " + 
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskModuleRequest));
       await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        
       return TaskModuleResponseFactory.CreateResponse("Thanks!");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you developing any Teams app? If yes could you please share the scenario what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The [Teams task module](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module) sample shows how to handle these in a bot.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, I have a bot that configures an iot device;  as part of the configuration steps in waterfall dialog, get the device id thru QR code, so one of the step in the waterfall dialog, calls the task module to scan the qr code that will be returned to the next step in the waterfall dialog.

Comment: I want to forward the response activity to the dialog waiting on the stack similar to oauth token event. I do call Dialog.RunAsync from the Bot class but no change.

Comment: @AP01, I have used the sample, however,  in the sample task module is NOT called from waterfall dialog.

Comment: Waterfall dialog step shows herocard where user click on the button that will invoke a task module (Razor page), everything works smoothly and got a response back from a user as a task/submit event activity, now, i need to route this response as a response to waterfall dialog step where it is waiting for the user's response from the hero card. I have tried calling DialogSet.CreateDialogContext and ContinueDialogAsync, but none works, Any pointers?

Comment: Have you attempted to start a waterfall dialog from the Task Module Submit function?

Comment: My flow is something like this: Bot<MainDialog> calls MainDialog-> calls ChildDialog which is a WaterfallDialog->WaterfallStep->Invoke Task Module as by sending HeroCard with Prompt (Step is waiting for the user response)->User interact with the task module (web page) when it is done task module sends task\submit that is received by the Bot. I want to resume the waterfall dialog

Comment: Reload the dialog using session.replaceDialog(). This will start you back at the beginning of the waterfall. If your waterfall isn't a separate dialog you should break it out to be a separate dialog.

Comment: You cannot resume a dialog once you've ended it and it has left the dialog stack. You will need to break it into multiple dialogs and start a new one.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, thanks for the feedback.  I have modified the task module sample to repro the issue which is that task module is called from the waterfall dialog (https://github.com/SonOfJesseAsSnekithan/54.teams-task-module.git),  Can you clarify based on the sample, you mean calling replaceDialog from OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync in DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs class. [type get_profile2 to repro the issue].

Comment: @AP01, it is in the dialog stack waiting for the response from user, but user made the response in the task module, now the question is how to route the response back to the waterfall dialog, similar to OAuthPrompt response.

Comment: @Snekithan - Could you please refer below document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-waterfall-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#to-end-a-dialog